# Selecting multiple values with partial multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

df1 has a multi index of A, B, C and D.
df2 has a multi index of A, B and C.

I want to select from df1 all the rows whose index appear in df2.

For example, if df2 contains a row with index A=1, B=1, C=1, I want to get all the rows from df1 with those values regardless of the value of D.

I tried doing `df1[df2.index]` and `df1.loc[df2.index]` but it does not work. I get "{ValueError}operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13838,3) (4,) (13838,3) " (where 13838 is the length of df2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use `isin` to check

```
df1 = df1[df1.reset_index(level=[3]).index.isin(df2.index)]
```